# How to apply multiple filters in an aggregation in polars while staying in streaming mode

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a large-ish dataset, and I would like to run several aggregations on it without loading the whole thing into memory. Specifically, I have a list of simple filters of the form `pl.col('x1') == 'y1'`, and I'd like get the result of my aggregation under each of these filters separately.

I can get the desired result by running

```py
dataset.filter(
  pl.col(x) == y
).groupby(pl.col('a')).agg(
  pl.col('b').sum()
).collect(streaming=True)
```

for each `x` and `y` separately, but I have somewhere on the order of a hundred different filters, so taking this many passes over the dataset is very time-consuming.

I expected that I should be able to get the desired result by doing something like

```py
dataset.groupby(pl.col('a')).agg(
  *[pl.col('b').filter(pl.col(x) == y).sum().alias(f'{x}={y}') for x, y in filters]
).collect(streaming=True)
```

but while this works for a small subset of the data, as soon as I try to run it on the full dataset (even with a single filter), the process consumes all memory on the machine and dies. I assume this means that polars is not running this query in streaming mode, even though all individual components I'm using should be streaming-compatible.

Is there a way to get my desired results using a single pass in streaming mode? Is this something that polars doesn't yet support?

Comment: I'm not sure, but - are you trying to pivot the dataframe? Maybe small example input and desired output would help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution here is to use `polars.when` instead of `polars.col.filter`. My working solution looks like:

```py
dataset.groupby(pl.col('a')).agg(
  *[pl.when(pl.col(x) == y)
    .then(pl.col('b'))
    .otherwise(pl.lit(0))
    .sum().alias(f'{x}={y}') for x, y in filters]
).collect(streaming=True)
```

which computes all my aggregations on a single pass of the dataset, without ever holding more than a fraction of the dataset in memory.

I'm still unclear on whether this difference in streaming support between `pl.col.filter` and `pl.when` is

- me misunderstanding the `col.filter` expression,
- a design constraint of the streaming API,
- a bug, or
- just a feature that has yet to be implemented.